# Unable to find solution to ^D error in yylex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

^D does not work in yylex() function

I know the basics of flex

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int c=0;
int blank=0;
int line=0;
int word=0;
%}
%%
([a-zA-z])+(" "|\n) {word++; int i=0; 
while(yytext[i]!='\0')
{
if(yytext[i]=' ') blank++;
else if(yytext[i]=='\n') line++;
}

}
" " {blank++;  c++;}
\n {line++; c++;}
. {c++;}
%%
int main()
{
yylex();
printf("The no of characters is %d\n",c);

printf("The no of blanks is %d\n",blank);

printf("The no of lines is %d\n",line);

printf("The no of words is %d\n",word);
}
```

I tried a lot but could not think of anything
. Please help I am stuck on this.

Comment: It does not respond to ^D when running

Comment: This `yytext[i]!="\0"` makes no sense... `yytext[i]` is a char and `"\0"` is a string. If anything it should be `yytext[i]!='\0'`

Comment: it does not work with char also

Comment: Are you entering `^D` via the keyboard, with your process reading from the terminal?

Comment: yeah i am doing it with the keyboard with the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole section of code makes absolutely no sense. You're looking for a series of letters followed by a space or newline and then doing a while loop to see when the first character (you never change the value of `i`) in `yytext` is equal to a string that happens to be empty?

```
([a-zA-z])+(" "|\n) {word++; int i=0; 
while(yytext[i]!="\0")
{
if(yytext[i]=" ") blank++;
else if(yytext[i]=="\n") line++;
}

}
```

If you're looking for the NUL terminating character you need to specify it as a character not put it in double quotes. And you also need to increment `i` so that you'll traverse the whole of `yytext`. As it currently stands, your `while` loop will never terminate, which explains why ^D isn't doing anything. But you don't need to do any of that.

Since all you're after is counting how many words there are, all you need to do is...

```
([a-zA-z])+ {word++;}
```

... since the other rules will handle counting spaces and newlines etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot that was clever